# symfony entity setmaxresult/limit on array collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to set a max amount of result when retrieving related objects in a one-to-many relationship using the "lazy load"?

Example:
Lets say a Person have shoes

```
$person = $em->find($id);
$person->getShoes();
```

This will fetch everything from the shoes table with `person_id`.
But what if I only want to show the last 5 shoes that where added to the db?

Or is the only solution use the Paginator and do:

```
$em->createQuery('...')->setMaxResult(5);
```

Comment: but don't forget about https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/3979  doctrine does **NOT** support LIMIT in subquery !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use doctrine's [`Criteria`](https://api.nellafw.org/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Criteria.html) class to filter/sort/limit your records

```
public function getShoes() {
    $criteria = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::create()
        ->orderBy(array('your_property_to_sort_collection'=> \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::DESC))
        ->setMaxResults(5);
    return $this->shoes->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i was looking for.